# Certain clients (IP range) can not ping server

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, hyper-v

I just virtualized a Windows 2003 Server SP2 x32. The server contained our help desk server (Spiceworks) and our anti virus management server (ESET RAC). The host computer actually contained the virtualized server originally; I created the vhd and then I wiped this system clean and installed Windows 2008 R2 x64 Datacenter and added the virtualized 2003 onto the Hyper-V 2008 R2 Server.

I got the server running fine except for... certain ip ranges.
Local clients can get updates from the AV server from my 192.168.180.xxx & 192.168.181.xxx
BUT NOT from any 192.168.182.xxx, 192.168.183.xxx, 192.168.184.xxx etc... I can not ping the server from any clients except for the 180. & 181. ranges.

Now I created 2 other virtualized servers (win2008 & a win7 pro) and they exist on the same virtual host as the 2003 server. And at first I could not ping those until I went to the "\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings" and Turned On File and Print Sharing. Then I could ping and access those virtualized guests.

Win2003 server isn't quite the same.

**EDIT!!** *Changed Image and added more info...*

[image]

> The ping test is from a host in the 192.168.187.x
>
> 192.168.181.200 is the server (Spiceworks/AV)
>
> hostname is cea-spiceworks (originally ois-imaging)

1. First ping cea-spiceworks = Request Timed out.
2. Second ping: 192.168.181.200 = Request Timed out.
3. Third ping test to cea-hyperv = Successful
   cea-hyperv is Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter x64 which holds the cea-spiceworks vhd virtual server.
4. Fourth ping is to a nas fileserver (192.168.181.30), which is on the same ip range as cea-spiceworks. And that ping was successful.

I can ping all other guests running on cea-hyperv, just not the 2003 Spiceworks Server. Which makes me believe it is the cea-spiceworks 2003 server and not dns.

btw, I did rename that 2003 Server (Spiceworks/AV) hostname. And I tried a CNAME. But I do not think that is the problem. **EDIT**: OR because this server existed on this hardware/computer before becoming virtualized?

Comment: File and Printer sharing as it's presented in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008/R2 isn't relevant to Windows Server 2003 and neither is required to ping a Windows Server 2003 server. Your screenshot is confusing. It's showing an ip address (192.168.181.200) where it should be showing the name, since you are pinging by name. The ip address that the name resolves to is shown in the brackets. Can you ping again and post the screenshot without obfuscating any of it?

Comment: I pinged "ois-imaging" which is the hostname for the 2003 server. Its IP is "192.168.181.200"  but a reply came from the 67.215.x.x and I have no idea why. If I ping using the IP instead of hostname or cname (alias) I get unkown host unreachable.

Comment: the ip ranges of the networks 182.x and higher are remote sites with a dedicated T1. I will try to get a better image tomorrow and clear things up more too

Comment: Keep in mind that `ping` won't work unless the machines you are pinging know how to reach *you* back. If you're not in the same subnet, that means they either need a specific route to your subnet or their default router has to know how to get traffic to you.

Comment: Do you get the same results pinging by IP as you do by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing the hidden physical network adapters.

> This can easily be removed by opening the command prompt with
>   administrative access and typing the following command:
>
> `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1`
>
> `start devmgmt.msc`
>
> When the Device Manager loads, from the File menu, expand the View and
>   select the Show Hidden Devices option. This will enable and show any
>   old un-used devices in the window. From here, expand the Network
>   Adapters node and you can right click on the devices which are extra
>   and delete them accordingly.

Not sure why I had to do this, maybe because this 2003 Server was originally on this hardware. But everything works correctly now. I can ping, and the AV clients can receive updates correctly.